# How to import Jquery RateYo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, webpack, rateyo

I'm trying to import Jquery Rateyo into my project, but it seems to not work.
Here's the code

```
import $ from "jquery";
import rateYo from "rateyo";

class Rating {
  constructor() {
    $(function() {
      $("#rateYo").rateYo({
        rating: 1.5,
        starWidth: "40px",
        numStars: 5,
        halfStar: true
      });
    });
  }
}

export default Rating;
```

I'm using webpack as well.

It does not show in the UI. And also generates an error saying,

> jquery.js?1157:3841 jQuery.Deferred exception:
>   jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).rateYo is not a
>   function TypeError:
>   jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).rateYo is not a
>   function at HTMLDocument.eval
>   (webpack-internal:///./js/modules/Rating.js:12:64) at mightThrow
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3557:29) at
>   process
>   (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3625:12)
>   undefined

Comment: Define "seems to not work".  In what specific way does this fail?

Comment: It does not show in the UI. And also generates an error saying, "jquery.js?1157:3841 jQuery.Deferred exception: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).rateYo is not a function TypeError: jquery__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0___default(...)(...).rateYo is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.eval (webpack-internal:///./js/modules/Rating.js:12:64)
    at mightThrow (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3557:29)
    at process (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js:3625:12) undefined"

Comment: Did you solve this issue? I am facing the same as well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use jquery version of the module `@rateyo/jquery`

and you can do the following.

```
import $ from "jquery";
import "@rateyo/jquery";

$("#rateyo").rateYo();
```

BTW rateyo expects jquery >= 3.0.0

Answer (score -1):

Two things I would check.
If the rateyo is in you package.json and if it has the folder in node_modules.

Another thing the import should be just:

```
import 'rateyo';
```

Comment: Rateyo is there in the package.json and it also has a folder in node_modules. I also made changed to import 'rateyo'. But still no change